# Quarkus security-jpa with custom PasswordProvider

Tags: quarkus, basic-authentication

I'm trying to get basic auth with jakarta persistence to work with a quarkus REST service. I followed the instructions on https://quarkus.io/guides/security-basic-authentication-tutorial but get stuck with a problem in a custom Password Provider.

Here's the relevant code:

User:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "pwd_table")
@UserDefinition 
public class LoginUser {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "USERID")
    public Long userid;
    
    @Column(name = "USERNAME")
    @Username
    public String username;

    @Column(name = "PWD_CRYPT")
    @Password(value = PasswordType.CUSTOM, provider = CustomPasswordProvider.class)
    public String password;
    
    @Roles
    public String roles;
    
}
```

PasswordProvider

```
public class CustomPasswordProvider implements PasswordProvider {
    
    public CustomPasswordProvider() {
        
    }
    
    @Override
    public org.wildfly.security.password.Password getPassword(String pass) {
        byte[] digest = MyHash.hash(pass) // simplified code, we use SCrypt here...
        return SimpleDigestPassword.createRaw("myhash", digest);
    }
}
```

```
@GET
@RolesAllowed("backoffice")
@Path("/{myId}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public Response getXML(@PathParam("myId") String myId) {
...
}
```

My expectation is that the password provided in the header of the http request is passed to the getPassword method in the PasswordProvider class in oder to hash this clear text password and compare it than to the hashed password that ist stored in the database for the authentication process.

What happens is the the hashed password from the database is passed to the PasswordProvider and is  hashed again there which makes no sense. The authentication fails of course (401 Unauthorized).

Probably i misunderstood something but i found no solution for this online.

Comment: I removed my previous comment as it was wrong as pointed out by my colleagues. We are checking it. Can you please open a bug issue ?

Comment: Thanks. I opened https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/35671

Comment: Thanks, clarification is on the way with https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/35682

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach was obviously the wrong one. The documentation was somwhat misleading her as pointed out in the discussion in the bug report https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/35671.

The right approach is a custom IdentityProvider:

https://quarkus.io/guides/security-identity-providers